# Get value of configMap from mountPath

Tags: kubernetes, volumes, configmap

I created configmap this way.

```
kubectl create configmap some-config --from-literal=key4=value1
```

After that i created pod which looks like this

.[image]

I connect to this pod this way

```
k exec -it nginx-configmap -- /bin/sh
```

I found the folder `/some/path` but i could get value from key4.

Comment: For literal values usage please [refer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-container-environment-variables-using-configmap-data)

Comment: Have u tried `ls /some/path/` to verify it?

Comment: Yes, i tried. The result is key4.

Comment: the content of key4 file should have value1

Comment: I tried the command echo $key4 but when i tried cat key4 the command lined showed value value1. Thanks

Comment: Could you run `kubectl get configmap some-config -o yaml` and attach the output to your question ? Looking at the comments I don't quite get your point. Do you want your value1 to be stored in $key4 environment variable or you want to store it within the file mounted in `/some/path` ? If you mounted your configmap as a file in your pod you cannot expect it to be available as env variable. _"I found the folder /some/path but i could get value from key4."_ - but you couldn't get it ?

Comment: @mario I thought that it could work as a variable but i did not want to use variable in pod definition. When i use cat command i saw the output as i wanted.

Comment: So does it currently work as you wanted ? Or you still want it to be available as a variable ?

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to your `ConfigMap` in your `Pod` this way:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: myfrontend
      image: nginx
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/var/www/html"
        name: config-volume
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        name: some-config
```

it will be available in your `Pod` as a file `/var/www/html/key4` with the content of `value1`.

If you rather want it to be available as an **environment variable** you need to refer to it this way:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: myfrontend
      image: nginx
      envFrom:
      - configMapRef:
          name: some-config
```

As you can see you don't need for it any volumes and volume mounts.

Once you connect to such `Pod` by running:

```
kubectl exec -ti mypod -- /bin/bash
```

You will see that your environment variable is defined:

```
root@mypod:/# echo $key4
value1
```